# Federated table of two LEFT JOIN tables not working

Tags: mysql

For some reasons I am getting the following error when executing the below query:
(What I am trying to achieve is to sync and merge two left-joined table to into one

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ENGINE=FEDERATED' at line 35

```
CREATE TABLE users AS (
  SELECT
    ID, user_email, user_registered,
    first_name.meta_value as first_name,
    last_name.meta_value as last_name,
    telephone.meta_value as telephone,
    country.meta_value as country,
    company.meta_value as company,
    address.meta_value as address,
    city.meta_value as city,
    professional_title.meta_value as professional_title,
    state.meta_value as state,
    areas_of_interest.meta_value as areas_of_interest
    FROM wp_users
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS first_name ON first_name.user_id=ID
        AND first_name.meta_key='first_name'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS last_name ON last_name.user_id=ID
        AND last_name.meta_key='last_name'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS telephone ON telephone.user_id=ID
        AND telephone.meta_key='telephone'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS country ON country.user_id=ID
        AND country.meta_key='country'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS company ON company.user_id=ID
        AND company.meta_key='company'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS address ON address.user_id=ID
        AND address.meta_key='address'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS city ON city.user_id=ID
        AND city.meta_key='city'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS professional_title ON professional_title.user_id=ID
        AND professional_title.meta_key='professional_title'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS state ON state.user_id=ID
        AND state.meta_key='state'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS areas_of_interest ON areas_of_interest.user_id=ID
        AND areas_of_interest.meta_key='areas_of_interest'
) ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 CONNECTION 'mysql://*********';
```

Note: FEDERATED Engine is on and working on other non-joined table.

Comment: Still not clear why ENGINE = FEDERATED is used ?

Comment: I wanted to remotely left-join and sync the two tables. but Now I am even interested to achieve the same without FEDERATED on local db if possible.

Answer (score 1):

To define a FEDERATED table the field definition on local table much match field types on remote table. You are creating a brand new table by joining existing tables. I don't think this is legal.

> A local server with a database table, where the table definition
>   matches that of the corresponding table on the remote server. The
>   table definition is stored within the .frm file. However, there is no
>   data file on the local server. Instead, the table definition includes
>   a connection string that points to the remote table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-description.html